# Graphs in xlsx File overwrite by openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

We need to update xlsx sheet using python script which do some calcualtion and update one worksheet.
I choose openpyxl as it supoort writing/updating xlsx File.
In the Excel sheet contain some graphs also but When I update excel sheet than graph does not work
into excel and data update respectively.
I think we had some issue for updating graph with openpyxl.Can anyone provide me some input to fix this issue

or In other word,In the Excel sheet I have 10 worksheet.In worksheet 1, it contain graphs. I have updated worksheet number 5. Worksheet is updated successfully. But I have loose the graphs of worksheet 1.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl 
print "pylx"
ddr_sam45_flop =  "Flip_Flop.xlsx"
flop_workbook     = load_workbook(ddr_sam45_flop)
raw_flop_workbook = flop_workbook.get_sheet_by_name(name ='RAW')
raw_flop_workbook.cell(row = 1 , column = 1).value = 889999
flop_workbook.save(ddr_sam45_flop)
print "End"
```

(Please consider me new to openpyxl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openpyxl does not support graphs or chart as of now

Answer (score 1):

Any graphs that exist in the document before opening will be deleted after saving.  The only way around this ( i know of) is to create the chart in code.

[Here](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/charts.html) is the documentation on how to create a chart in openpyxl

The example is a little broken, compare to this instead.

```
    values = Reference(ws, (1, 1), (1, 95))
    series = Series(values, title="Sample" )
    chart = LineChart()
    chart.append(series)
    ws.add_chart(chart)
```

Comment: would it be possible to find an existing chart, copy it, and add it back in rather than creating it manually?

Comment: @LegitStack This does not seem to work from my testing. The save action recreates the xml document which deletes the chart. Real shame as I wanted this feature also.

Comment: new link: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/introduction.html